# (WebGL) Point light per-fragment issue

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm using an FPS-like camera, this is the code:

**CAMERA**

```
mat4.identity(mat.mvMatrix);
mat4.rotate(mat.mvMatrix,degToRad(-camera.pitch),[1,0,0]);
mat4.rotate(mat.mvMatrix,degToRad(-camera.yaw),[0,1,0]);
mat4.translate(mat.mvMatrix,[-camera.pos[0],-camera.pos[1],-camera.pos[2]]);
```

The above code produces the *model-view matrix* as i roam the map (handling the camera position via *WSAD* style keys)
The `uMVMatrix` from vertex shader is the passed `mat.mvMatrix` from the above code.

I'm also using a shader for *point lighting per-fragment* in WebGL, the fragments are:

**VS**

```
vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
// pass to fragment shader
vColorLight = uColorLight;
vColorAmbient = uColorAmbient;
vLightPosition = uLightPosition;
```

**FS**

```
vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition.xyz);
float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(normalize(vTransformedNormal), lightDirection), 0.0);
vec3 lightWeighting = vColorAmbient + vColorLight * directionalLightWeighting;
vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTex0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * lightWeighting, textureColor.a);
```

The `vLightPosition` is actually the camera's position (the light position moves as i move around)
I don't have a problem by moving around and putting correctly transformed objects.
But my lighting position seems to *run away from me* (i can't describe it better) as i roam the map. At position *[0,0,0]* is good, but as i move from there i can see actually the light source goes far away, and actually *sinking* (although i'm not changing my height =Y position)

Surprisingly, i solved the above problem by multiplying the input `vLightPosition` by **0.00054687** (!) before i send it to shader, where it gave me a centered bulb in the terrain. I post 2 images to illustrate this:

*When i multiply my light position by the above number..*.

```
var lightPosition = [5,2,5];   // just example
gl.uniform3f(gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uLightPosition"),
             parseFloat(lightPosition[0])*0.00054687,
             parseFloat(lightPosition[1])*0.00054687,
             parseFloat(lightPosition[2])*0.00054687);
```

[image]

*When i'm passing light position directly as camera position..*

```
var lightPosition = [5,2,5];   // just example
gl.uniform3f(gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uLightPosition"),
             parseFloat(lightPosition[0]),
             parseFloat(lightPosition[1]),
             parseFloat(lightPosition[2]));
```

[image]

In fact you can hardly see a light source that comes from far, far away (stones are lit).

It seems i need to *scale down my input light position to microscope level*, yet i dont understand why and though i solved it mostly by luck, i would like to know where's the problem to prevent future issues.
Thanx

**EDIT**

My full shader fragments:

**VS**

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;  
uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

// lighting
uniform int uLightType;
// general
uniform vec3 uColorAmbient;
uniform vec3 uColorLight;
// directional light
uniform vec3 uLightDirection;
// point light
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;

varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
varying vec4 vPosition;

// lighting on fragment shader
varying vec3 vColorAmbient;
varying vec3 vColorLight;
varying vec3 vLightPosition;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

void main(void) {
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    // none light
    if (uLightType==0) {
       gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
       vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    // directional light
    else if (uLightType==1) {
       gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
       vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
       float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightDirection), 0.0);
       vLightWeighting = uColorAmbient + uColorLight * directionalLightWeighting;
    }
    // point light (per-fragment)
    else if (uLightType==2) {
       vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
       gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
       vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
       // pass to fragment shader
       vColorLight = uColorLight;
       vColorAmbient = uColorAmbient;

       vLightPosition = uLightPosition;
       //      vLightPosition = uMVMatrix * uLightPosition;
       //      vLightPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0);
       //      vLightPosition = (uMVMatrix * uLightPosition).xyz;
               vLightPosition = (uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz;

    }
 }
```

**FS**

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vLightWeighting;
uniform sampler2D uTex0;

uniform int fLightType;
varying vec4 vPosition;
varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
// lighting
varying vec3 vColorAmbient;
varying vec3 vColorLight;
varying vec3 vLightPosition;

void main(void) {
   // point light (per-fragment)
   if (fLightType==2) {
      vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition.xyz);

      float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(normalize(vTransformedNormal), lightDirection), 0.0);

      vec3 lightWeighting = vColorAmbient + vColorLight * directionalLightWeighting;
      vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTex0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
      gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * lightWeighting, textureColor.a);
   }
   else {
      vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTex0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
      gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);

   }
}
```

**EDIT2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition.xyz);
```

`vPosition` is in view/camera space, `vLightPosition` is in world space, hence the buggy results.

You need to transform your light from world coordinates to view coordinates, i.e. multiply the light coordinates by the view matrix (just as you multiplied the position by the model-view matrix).

Comment: I did `vLightPosition = uMVMatrix * uLightPosition` but since light position is a vec3 and not vec4 (like vPosition) it doesnt allow me.

Comment: So make it a vec4: `uMVMatrix * vec4(vLightPosition, 1.0);`

Comment: I tried that too with error `ERROR: 0:56: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '-component vector of float' to 'varying mediump -component vector of float'`

Comment: It's probably complaining about trying to assign a vec4 to a vec3. Try it like this: `vLightPosition = (uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz;`

Comment: Lots of errors now :). They are:  `ERROR: 0:57: '*' :  wrong operand types  no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uniform mediump X matrix of float' and a right operand of type 'uniform mediump -component vector of float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:57: 'xyz' : illegal length of matrix field selection 
ERROR: 0:57: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'float' to 'varying mediump -component vector of float'`

Comment: It would help, yes, if you posted the full vertex shader.

Comment: I can't tell what it's throwing errors for. `vLightPosition = (uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz;` _should_ work, it's the exact same thing you are doing with gl_Position in =0, except with an added .xyz swizzle. I just tried the syntax in a shader of my own, it worked just fine.

Comment: Check my second edit (image) in my post, it seems the bulb is finally centered under me with your help, hence no lighting in front of wall. It seems the bulb moves with me but like without spiting light :)

Comment: So the light is moving as it should, but it's not lighting things up properly? Try negating `lightDirection` in your fragment shader (if the dot product is negative, `max()` will return 0.0).

Comment: Do you mean this: `float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(normalize(vTransformedNormal), -lightDirection), 0.0)`. Seems like it negates normals as well (i got bulb under terrain). I'm not sure if it helps, but seems like light source comes somewhere from the right, yet bulb is right under me. Weird.

Comment: It's not that then. Just one more point, you are currently multiplying the light position by the model-view matrix. That means that any transformations applied to the model you are currently rendering will be applied to the light as well. To avoid this you are going to have to pass the view matrix to the vertex shader as well, use that for your light position computation.

Comment: Hmm it seems there was a huge problem with original model's normals as well. I recalculated them via a function of mine (typical per-face) and problem seems was already solved by your latest solution `(.xyz)` above which centered the light position. I thought i was already sending the model's transform via `UMVMatrix`; this one is sent just before each call to `gl.drawArrays`. I hope it's over now :)